# Change files with Editor that need sudo permissions

Tags: debian, permissions, sudo

I want to change files with KomodoEdit that need `sudo` permissions. I can't start KomodoEdit with `sudo`, though (for whatever reason). Can I somehow grant Komodo permission to edit those files (in particular I am talking about apache2 files and `/etc/hosts`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sudoedit <file>`. It creates a local copy of the file, edits it with user rights and copies it back to the original location. The advantage is that the editor is running as regular user.

To specify a different editor than the default one you can set `EDITOR` temporarily:

```
EDITOR=/usr/bin/someeditor sudoedit /etc/hosts
```

This requires the `sudo` package to be installed and the user to be added to the `sudo` group.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is it a good idea/even possible to permanently change the EDITOR variable (echoing it shows me its actually empty by default)?

Comment: Sure, it's possible to change the default `EDITOR`. Since this is a per-user setting you might consider adding the corresponding assignment e.g. to `~/.profile`.

Comment: Hmm, I added `export EDITOR=/etc/home/***/Komodo-Edit-9/bin/komodo` to the `~/.profile` file but its still using nano as standard. Which is confusing because changing `PATH` in the exact same way worked for me.

Comment: whooops i am retarded, that /etc/ didnt belong in the path^^

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could do that by setting the suid bit on komodoedit, and changing it's owner to root.

```
sudo chown root:root /path/to/komodoedit
sudo chmod u+s /path/to/komodoedit
```

What it does:

1. `chown` sets the owner to root
2. `chmod u+s` gives anyone who executes the file the same rights (for the execution) as the owner.

Since we've set the owner to root, the effective execution owner becomes root.

This is probably NOT the answer you seek, as it will grant all users effective root editor.

sudoedit, as mentioned by marco, is probably more correct, security wise.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively clean way is to give your user id permissions to a given file using *access control lists*. You will probably need to install the `acl` package to have the commands `getfacl` and `setfacl`.  Then for a user "myname" and a file `/etc/hosts` you can give the command:

```
sudo setfacl -m 'u:myname:rw' /etc/hosts
```

and you will then be able to read/write this file. When you `ls -l` on the file you will see a `+` sign to show there is an acl for the file:

```
-rw-r--r--+ 1 root root 221 Nov  5 16:55 /etc/hosts
```

and you can list the acl with `getfacl` on the file. To remove the acl later on use

```
sudo setfacl -x 'u:myname' /etc/hosts
```

or `setfacl -b` to remove all acls. (Your filesystem must support acls.)